# Autoresize View When SubViews are Added

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am developing an app using iOS 7 and auto layout. I am adding a simple textfield to a UIView. But the view is not getting resized. I even tried to change the frame manually but it did not work. I believe it is because I am using auto layout. Here is my code:

```
-(void) setupViewForSignUp
{
    UITextField *firstNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.passwordTextField.frame.origin.x, self.passwordTextField.frame.origin.y + 40, self.passwordTextField.bounds.size.width, self.passwordTextField.bounds.size.height)];
    firstNameTextField.placeholder = @"First Name";
    firstNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.3;
    firstNameTextField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
    firstNameTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    [self.signUpLoginContainerView addSubview:firstNameTextField];

    self.signUpLoginContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because you are using auto layout. Setting the view frame and resizing mask will not work.

You should read [Working with Auto Layout Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1) and [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1).

You will need to get the current constraints, add the text field, adjust the contraints for the text field, then add the correct constraints on the text field.